# Would medical decision making aspect of my question be in scope for this site?

Tags: discussion

Please reference [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/177305/how-to-express-concern-with-an-unsafe-practice-in-a-hospital-setting-if-quitting) of mine from The Workplace SE.

I am trying to work with my wife to assist her with how to discuss with hospital management her concerns that ventilating multiple patients on a single ventilator is unsafe. She also has a departmental meeting coming up with other respiratory therapists and allied health colleagues such as CRNA / Anesthesia.

Is a question on what factors are considered when coventilating patients with Covid 19 and how such factors are weighed against expert advice advocating the opposite action appropriate for this site?

Comment: Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it is. In fact, I think Workplace is the right place for it. However, if you're going to rewrite the question to make it about the medical aspects of mechanical ventilation and how it could affect two patients on the same machine, that would be more in line with MedSci. But the aspects of the problem relating to management decisions, interactions with staff, and so forth would definitely be off topic. And do keep in mind that you can't ask the same question in two forums. The question on Workplace would have to be substantially changed to be accepted here.

Comment: OK, sample questions would include how safety concerns can be mitigated, and given the linked article advocating against sharing, how allied health professionals such as her decide which patients are selected for sharing. If I focus on on clinical questions, is this acceptable?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, no, maybe? Compose the question and post it. We'll see how it works out and if necessary you can edit it.